# add a User Header Search Path to a podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods

This is a follow-up to this question: [possible to have a CocoaPods have a search path that includes the main app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163766/possible-to-have-a-cocoapods-have-a-search-path-that-includes-the-main-app)

I'd like to add add a `User Header Search Path` to my .podspec so that it is added when I compile but I'm not sure how to do this so that it's effect is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this code to your `.podspec` file:

```
s.xcconfig = { 'USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PROJECT_DIR}/.."' }
```

To set path `recursive`:

```
s.xcconfig = { 'USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PROJECT_DIR}/.."/**' }
```

I did Google and this [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/98) on GitHub helped me.

Comment: See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#pod_target_xcconfig It seems attribute xcconfig has been deprecated, use pod_target_xcconfig instead.